# Laravel Form Takes Incorrect Record ID for Deleting

Tags: laravel

I have two buttons (edit and delete) in the index view where I can edit the record properly but when I delete the record, the laravel form takes the id of another record for deletion.

This is view:

```
<div class="row">
                    @if(App\Player::count()>0)
                      @foreach($players as $player)
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                            <div class="thumbnail no-padding">
                                <div class="thumb">
                                    <img src="/cricket/storage/images/players/{{ $player->photo }}" alt="">
                                    <div class="caption-overflow">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="/cricket/storage/images/players/{{ $player->photo }}" class="btn bg-success-400 btn-icon btn-xs" data-popup="lightbox"><i class="icon-plus2"></i></a>
                                            <a href="user_pages_profile.html" class="btn bg-success-400 btn-icon btn-xs"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="caption text-center">
                                    <h6 class="text-semibold no-margin">{{ $player->name }}</h6>
                                    <ul class="icons-list mt-15">

                                        <li><a href="{{ route('players.edit', $player->id) }}" data-popup="tooltip" title="Edit" data-container="body"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></li>
                                        <li></li><li></li><li></li>

                                        <li>

                                        {!! Form::open(['id' => 'p', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['players.destroy', $player->id]]) !!}

                                        <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('p').submit();" data-popup="tooltip" title="Delete" data-container="body"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                  @endif

                </div>
```

This is the delete method:

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $record = Player::find($id);
    $filename = $record->photo;   

    if(Storage::exists('players/' . $filename))
    {
        Storage::delete($filename);
        //return "yyy";
    }

    $record->delete();

    Session::flash('success', 'The record was successfully deleted.');

    return redirect()->route('players.index');
}
```

I added a text field and displayed the ID of the record where it shows the correct ID as below screenshot but when I submit the form for deletion, it takes incorrect id:
[image: ID 9]

When I display the ID from the delete method, it shows 5 instead of 9:

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    return $id;
}
```

The above code returns 5 which is incorrect, it should return 9, below is the result of the return statement:

[image: ID 5]

I don't know what goes wrong here.
Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: the player->id looks okay to me,it is correcty sending the url id to the destroy method,zadran looks like he has the id of nine but are the two images on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the 'p' is unique foreach record. You can acheive this by concatenating the player id to it.

```
@foreach($players as $player)
    {!! Form::open(['id{{$player->id}}' => 'p', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['players.destroy', $player->id]]) !!}
    <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('p{{$player->id}}').submit();" data-popup="tooltip" title="Delete" data-container="body"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Your codes seem well,

Can you try delete record by query like this,

```
$record = Player::where('id', $id)->first();
...
$record->delete();
```

I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your html/javascript. Your form generation basically looks like this, if you simplify it:

```
@foreach($players as $player)
    {!! Form::open(['id' => 'p', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['players.destroy', $player->id]]) !!}
    <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('p').submit();" data-popup="tooltip" title="Delete" data-container="body"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```

Each player form is getting the same id ("p") since you generate the form inside a foreach-loop. I think what's happening is, that the javascript just picks the first form, instead of the one you are trying to submit, because your id is not unique anymore.

A possible solution would be to add some kind of enumerator to the form id (e.g. `p-{{ $player->id }}`) or find a different way of selecting the correct form to submit, e.g. search for the parent form of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! Form::open(['class' => 'p', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['players.destroy', $player->id]]) !!}
```

I've had the same issues, but after changes the id to class it works